# Best way to play m3u8 in flutter

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, m3u8

I am using cloudflares stream service to host videos.

Cloudflare offers hsl / m3u8 playback for variable quality video streams.

Until now I used to use Chewie for Video playback, but my problem is that the automatic playback can take quit long for some users to initiate and sometimes fails altogether, so I'd like to manually set the Video Quality to be streamed.

Unfortunatly Chewie does not seem to support the quality selection of m3u8, and parsing the m3u8 file and replacing the source files with the diffrent qualities bares the issue that cloudflare delivers the audio seperatly from the video, but I can't figure out a way to make that work with Chewie, or any of the players I found on pub dev really.

So, does anybody know of a plugin that properly supports m3u8 or has some other workaround that would work?

Thanks <3